# Error when trying to connect bluetooth device via ExternalAccessory framework: "Unsupported Legacy Device"

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

We have a device with an MFI chip we would like to connect through right from the app.

Using `EAAccessoryManager.shared().showBluetoothAccessoryPicker`, we can indeed see the peripheral appear in the picker after a few seconds.

If we tap on it, it will load for a moment, then display the following error :

> **Unsupported Legacy Device**
>
> Please go to Settings to pair with "DEVICE_NAME"

For some reason, once we've connected once through Settings > Bluetooth, we are then able to connect from the app using the same exact method.

Comment: Does your peripheral include an iAP over Bluetooth unique ID in its extended inquiry response?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your comment. I'm not sure about this, how could I check that it is the case?

Comment: You would have to ask the people who are creating your hardware. I believe that if your peripheral doesn't include the required data then it must be paired through settings.

Comment: Thanks @paulw11 this was also my conclusion, we'll see how it goes!

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: Didn't exactly solve it, but now we use Secure Simple Pairing from the firmware side, which allows us to pair without going in the Settings.